# What's wrong with my Hive-UDF?How to set the map number of hive?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive

I use Hadoop-Hive to analyse apache log to statis access features. I write a UDF named GetCity to convert the remote_ip to city name, but when I run "select GetCity(remote_ip) from log_pre;", it's very slow, and even failed when the data is too large as more than 1000 items.
I tried to set mapred.reduce.tasks=10, but the jobtracker shown the map total num is 1 all the same. How can I set more maps when select?

Answer (score 0):

When performing a query like this the "GetCity(remote_ip)" call always happens on the mapper. In fact, I am doubtful there is anything going on in the reducer here except for maybe file concatenation. You can control the number of tasks that get used in the mapper from hive by calling:

SET mapred.map.tasks=10;

Hope this helps,

synctree